# Get users who replied the first message of the conversation within 24hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the users who replied the **first message** of the conversation (one to one conversation) within **24hours**. I have a messages table where all data are stored.

Table: messages

```
id | sender_id | recipient_id | content      | Created_at
1  | 1001      | 256          | Hi           | 2017-03-20 22:37:30
2  | 256       | 1001         | Hello        | 2017-03-21 20:29:10
3  | 1001      | 256          | XYZ          | 2017-03-21 22:02:00
4  | 256       | 1001         | ???          | 2017-03-21 23:01:01
5  | 1002      | 500          | Hi there     | 2017-03-22 10:10:10
6  | 1002      | 500          | Can you meet?| 2017-03-22 10:15:32
7  | 500       | 1002         | Yes          | 2017-03-22 10:20:30
8  | 1003      | 600          | Hello world  | 2017-03-23 01:00:00
9  | 1004      | 700          | Hi           | 2017-03-23 08:10:10
10 | 700       | 1004         | hello        | 2017-03-26 22:00:00
```

Expected result:

```
users
256
500
```

**Example**: Conversation between user 1001 and 256.

```
id | sender_id | recipient_id | content      | Created_at
1  | 1001      | 256          | Hi           | 2017-03-20 22:37:30
2  | 256       | 1001         | Hello        | 2017-03-21 20:29:10
3  | 1001      | 256          | XYZ          | 2017-03-21 22:02:00
4  | 256       | 1001         | ???          | 2017-03-21 23:01:01
```

Here `2  | 256       | 1001         | Hello        | 2017-03-21 20:29:10` is the first replied message of the conversation and its replied within 24 hours.

Comment: You want a list of all users who returned a message to the same individual they received one from, within a 1day window ?

Comment: how do you identify replies? what do you mean by first message of the conversation?

Comment: You are right @SLWS

Comment: @vkp id 2 is the first message or reply of the conversation between users 1001 and 256. I want users who replied the conversation with 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this out and it works. It's much the same as the other answers though.

```
select messages.sender_id as users from (
    select t.id1, t.id2, t.start, messages.sender_id as initiator,
    messages.recipient_id as replier from (
        select greatest(sender_id, recipient_id) as id1,
        least(sender_id, recipient_id) as id2, min(Created_at) as start
        from messages group by id1, id2
    ) as t left join messages on messages.Created_at = t.start
    and ((messages.sender_id = t.id1 and messages.receiver_id = t.id2)
    or (messages.sender_id = t.id2 and messages.receiver_id = t.id1))
) as t inner join messages on messages.sender_id = t.replier
and messages.recipient_id = t.initiator
and messages.Created_at < date_add(t.start, interval 1 day)
group by users;
```

The innermost query finds conversations by grouping messages by the two users involved, and finds the start of that conversation by taking the minimum `Created_at`.

The middle query finds the initiator and replier by looking up the first message in the conversation.

The outside query finds messages from the replier to the initiator (which are therefore in that conversation) within one day of the start of it, and groups by users so that they each appear only once (even if involved in multiple conversations).

Comment: "left join messages on messages.Created_at = t.start" : I'd add an extra test on sender and receiver id in case 2 messages have the same timestamp (unless the timestamp column is unique)

Comment: Good point. It just requires a little juggling as the sender and receiver could be either way round. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.

First, we need to define what a conversation is: a pair of  (sender_id, recipient_id) exchanging messages. Determining the first message in a conversation is a bit tricky. We could do this:

```
SELECT sender_id, recipient_id, min(created_at) FROM messages
GROUP BY sender_id, recipient_id
```

However, this will give us the first two messages of each conversation instead. We still don't know who started it and who replied without looking at the date, but the data we get is all we need to answer the question. And it is likely to be fast, since I will assume an index on (sender_id, recipient_id, created_at).

Now, I see two ways to solve this. First one:

```
SELECT least(sender_id,recipient_id), 
       greatest(sender_id,recipient_id),
       max(created_at) <= DATE_ADD( min(created_at), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
FROM (
    SELECT sender_id, recipient_id, min(created_at) FROM messages
    GROUP BY sender_id, recipient_id
) foo 
GROUP BY least(sender_id,recipient_id), 
       greatest(sender_id,recipient_id)
HAVING count(*)=2;
```

least() and greatest() allow to create one id for each conversation from the sender and receiver ids. max() and min() will return the first message and its reply, since we have only 2 rows per conversation. And the having will remove messages without reply.

We could also use a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (
    sender_id     INT NOT NULL, 
    recipient_id  INT NOT NULL, 
    createdèat    DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo
SELECT sender_id, recipient_id, min(created_at) FROM messages
GROUP BY sender_id, recipient_id

ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (sender_id,recipient_id);

SELECT ... substract a.created_at and b.created_at to get your 24h limit
FROM foo a
JOIN foo b ON (    a.sender_id=b.recipient_id 
               AND a.recipient_id=b.sender_id
               AND a.created_at < b.created_at)
```

By joining the temp table to itself, we put together the first message and its reply in a single query, and we can compare their dates.

Comment: this is close except for the case where there are two messages from the sender and then one reply later

Comment: Yeah, this query will take time from first message, not second one. Was that what you wanted?

Comment: That isn't what the OP wanted -- they wanted to compare to the REPLY message

Comment: yeah, this one compares the first message sent by a user to the first reply received... but if the user sent 2 messages before the reply, then the 2nd one will be ignored

Comment: It does not compare to the first reply it compares to the next message in the "conversation"  add another column to your sub-query that is the "sender" of the message and then you can find the first reply.

Comment: I'm thinking *To tired to think about the details* is maybe not the time to be answering hard SQL questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, a beer happened between posting the answer and right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a swing without testing, as I think the desired result is still unclear.

First, find the "first messages" of a conversation:

```
select m1.id
      ,m.sender_id
      ,m.recipient_id
      ,m.Created_at
from messages m1
inner join (
    select m.sender_id
          ,m.recipient_id
          ,Min(m.Created_at) as first_message
    from messages m
    group by m.sender_id
            ,m.recipient_id
    ) m2
   on m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id
   and m1.m.recipient_id = m2m.recipient_id
   and m1.Created_at = m2.first_message
```

If these are properly "first messages", then find any replies in 24 hours

```
select distinct m3.sender_id
from messages m3
inner join (
     <the above first message select statement>
     ) fm
   on m3.sender_id = fm.recipient_id
   and m3.recipient_id = fm.sender_id
   and m3.Created_at < DATEADD (HH , 24 , fm.Created_at)
where m3.Created_at > fm.Created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

this return the last message in 24 hours between to users

```
select 
     cnv.id ,
     cnv.sender_id,
     cnv.recipient_id,
     cnv.content,
     cnv.Created_at
from 
    (
    -- first create a table with costum id of conversaton 
    select 
         -- ex: 1001-256 
         concat(greatest(sender_id, recipient_id),'-',least(sender_id, recipient_id) ) as 'cnv_id', --  costum column for joining 
         id ,
         sender_id,
         recipient_id,
         content,
         Created_at
    from message 
     ) cnv 
          INNER JOIN 
            (
            -- second extract the last date of every one to one coversation conversation
            -- result ex : 1001-256 | 2017-03-21 23:01:01
                 SELECT 
                   concat(greatest(sender_id, recipient_id),'-',least(sender_id, recipient_id) )  as 'cnv_id', -- costum column for joining 
                   max(Created_at)  'max_date'
                 group by cnv_id
            ) max_cnv   ON  cnv.cnv_id = max_cnv.cnv_id -- join the two result by the custom cnv_id
    WHERE
      -- here we extract only the record that there Created_at is > 24 hours from the max date
      -- you can make this condition as you want but i think this will work
      (max_cnv.max_date - cnv.Created_at)/1000/60 >= 24;
```

Comment: sorry for answering this but i just love this kind of query hope that you try it and tell me if it work for you thank you !!!